# It's a list question - How can I word it in a way that it will be unlikely to be closed?

Tags: discussion

> I am looking for examples of monarchs who became monarchs through birthright, who subsequently became loved by the masses.
>
> Any period of history, up to and including the present day, is fair game.
>
> Perhaps a top five? Especially with examples of benevolence. I am not interested in monarchs who became popular as a result of skillful propaganda.

It will be my first question on History.SE. I am very interested in potential answers. I *hate* having my questions closed!

Comment: You might consider looking at the featured meta article: [Why did I get a downvote?](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-i-get-a-downvote?cb=1) Asking for a clickbait-style subjective list on this stack is indeed likely a one-way ticket to Hold Town.

Comment: Do you believe that this question is more likely to generate debate or answers?  How can the question be refined so that it is more likely to generate an objective answer and less likely to generate debate and discussion?

Comment: I don't think a question like this can avoid being closed. Leaving aside the problematic list element, "beloved by the masses" is strongly opinion based and whether their popularity was due to "skillful propaganda" even more so. Virtually all governments use propaganda in some way and how you evaluate its effects is not objectively measurable.

Comment: OK, I understand. I'm a mod on the cooking stack so I'm not completely clueless about such matters. I'll ask on Quora and then maybe come back here with a specific follow up. FWIW, I'm slowly watching (and reading) Game of Thrones. I was very moved by Ser Jorah's lines to Daenerys (paraphrasing), "You will be *loved*, thousands of years pass without a leader like that."

Comment: @Jolenealaska One of my favourite scenes ^.^  I hope you find what you're looking for. Some Chinese examples that might qualify: Emperors Wen and Xuan of Han, Renzhong of Song, and Ren and Xuan of Ming.